# How Do I Get A Bound Function Object from a wxPython Widget?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a script that allows the user to dynamically create fields.  One of the fields is a button which opens up a dialog box for user input, the other two are text inputs.  For the two text imputs, retrieving the user input was fairly simple and can be done by creating a list of all sizer objects in a sizer, then getting the widget object of each of these, then its value as shown below.

```
for sizerItem in sizer.GetChildren():
    userInput = sizerItem.GetWindow().GetValue()
```

However, this breaks down if the widget is a button, because the button has no value.  So what I need is something like `GetWindow()` that will return the function to which the widget object is bound. So then

```
exampleBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Do Stuff")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.exampleFunc, exampleBtn)  #with exampleFunc defined elsewhere

print exampleBtn.GetFunctions()
```

Would return:

```
['exampleFunc object']
```

**EDIT:** So here's a more proper explanation of what is going on here.  There is a "row" of widgets that contains two text inputs, and one button.  The button is bound to a function, the function creates a dialog box, and the user selects items from a list in this dialog box.  The user can add/remove these rows of widgets at will (zero rows is possible).  So what needs to happen is that the button in each row allows the items to be selected independently of other rows.  This is already being done with the text input.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the user selects items from the dialog box? Do those selections go into the text controls that are in the row with the button?

Comment: No, the selections go into a separate dictionary along with one of the text control inputs (lumped as a list), where one text control is the key. 

However, I managed to get a work around.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this that's built into wxPython. However, when you create the button, you could create a data structure that keeps that information handy. Something like this, perhaps:

```
self.handlers = {}
self.count  = 0
```

Ignore the count for now. Then in the method that creates the widget(s), you would do

```
self.handlers[exampleBtn: [] ]
self.handlers[exampleBtn].append(self.exampleFunc)
```

However, I would probably use a unique name when I create the buttons to use for the keys instead of the button object itself. So when you create the button, you'd do something like this:

```
exampleBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Test", name="btn%s" % self.count)
self.count += 1
```

Then you can create the handlers dict like this:

```
self.handlers[exampleBtn.GetName(): [] ]
self.handlers[exampleBtn.GetName()].append(self.exampleFunc)
```

This way you can check what functions it's attached to using

```
self.handlers["btn0"]
```

I hope all that rambling makes sense.

Comment: So what you're saying is then ```self.handlers``` would be dictionary of all the buttons created with their corresponding function objects.  This makes sense, but since there are many buttons, and only one function definition, will all the function objects in this dictionary be the same?

Comment: Yes. If you want to do the reverse and have the handler tell you which button called it, then you might find this article helpful: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

Comment: So then this isn't good.  If all the function objects are identical, there's no way of retrieving the data for each unique case.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but you said you were able to retrieve the information already using that function. If you want to associate the button with the text widgets, then you could give them similar names or but the whole lot of widgets together in some kind of list of tuples or list of lists. Then when the function is called by the button, you look in the list for the other two widgets and call their respective GetValue() methods.

Comment: No, I think the problem is on my end for not explaining fully. I updated the question to have a more full explanation, let me know if this makes sense or if you need more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
import wx

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Get widget value", pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                           size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        v_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 300), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.button_validator = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"call_validation", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                          0)
        self.button_validator.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.call_validation)
        self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes.Add(self.button_validator, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


        lista = range(0, 5)
        for number in lista:
            name = 'check_box_' + str(number)
            self.check_box = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Check Me!", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                         name=name)
            self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes.Add(self.check_box, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            print(self.check_box.GetName())


        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes.Fit(self.panel)
        v_box.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(v_box)
        self.Layout()
        v_box.Fit(self)

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def call_validation(self,event):
        children = self.sizer_of_button_validator_and_chek_boxes.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            widget = child.GetWindow()
            if isinstance(widget, wx.CheckBox):
                print(widget.GetName(),widget.GetValue())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyDialog(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```